# how to mimic operations on browsers' window by using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

do you happen to know any approach to mimic minimize - maximize - full screen the browser's window through JavaScript/jquery ?

is it even possible to do these things by using JavaScript ?

Comment: as far as i know the answer is NO, as this is manipulating native buttons, u can in some case `preventDefault` of an event such as when someone clicks, on a `<a></a>` tag or some other events,but its useless, if you could do that u might aswell get the permission to delete a users,file or take control of their whole computer :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes: http://www.codelifter.com/main/tips/tip_018.shtml

But this behaviour can be switched off by users who find it immensely irritating along with popups, popunders, blink tags, adverts etc etc. So 1) Don't rely on it, and 2) Just Don't Do It.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this...

But I think jquery already has in-built features similar to maximizing and minimizing a div...

Please correct me if I am wrong...